# Recyclerview agrupado

Tags: android

Estou tentando fazer um recyclerview agrupado mas estou tendo bastante dificuldade. Há um tempo atrás vi uma lib que iria me servir mas não recordo onde vi.

Fiz um desenho para explicar melhor minha dúvida, eu acho.

[image: exemplo]

Comment: Voce pode usar um CardView dentro do ReciclerView e mandar os dados já agrupados para inflar os itens conforme desejar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente o [android-arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/free). Eu já usei esta biblioteca [aqui](https://github.com/edubarr/header-decor).

Comment: Parece boa, vou testar no meu app. Obrigado.